# Javascript/jQuery replace every first text to specific text in string after comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to replace every first text with `+62` every after comma in string.

Example string:

```
var phonelist = "0812123456, 081278910, 08221177829";
```

So the result should be like this:

```
"+62812123456, +6281278910, +628221177829"
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: Why not try [`.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)?

Comment: Looks like a job for Regex.

Comment: You can split with comma and then replace first character and then join it again. Simple

Comment: `phonelist.replaceAll(/\b0/g, '+62')` might also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the `phonelist`  by `,`. Then, Update each number by replacing `0` with `+62`.

```js
const phonelist = "0812123456, 081278910, 08221177829";
const updatedPhoneList = phonelist.split(", ").map( v => v.replace("0", "+62"));

console.log(updatedPhoneList)

// Convert back to string
console.log( updatedPhoneList.join(", "))
```

Comment: Just an FYI to anyone reading:  `.replace("", "")` in [tag:javascript] only replaces the *first* value.  `.replaceAll(..` would also change all `0`.

Comment: @freedomn-m we only need to change first `0`. Why do we need `replaceAll()` here?

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding.  `.replace()` *is correct* here.   In other languages, generally `replace` means `replace all` - so the instinct is that `.replace` will replace all (and thus be incorrect) - but in JS you would need `replaceAll`

Comment: No need to apologies, We can also use `replaceAll` but with proper `Regex`